# Writing web table data to excel

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have nearly `1500 rows` in web table, I want to write all the rows data to excel.

I'm using `Selenium-Webdriver,Java`. problem is program stopped without any error after writing nearly 300 rows.

Please help me on this, How to write all the data to excel. if i give `thraed.sleep(5000);` its taking more time.

I have used below mentioned code:

```
  List<WebElement> irows =   a2.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_result']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[1]"));     
  int iRowsCount = irows.size();

 System.out.println(iRowsCount);



 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("E:\\jega\\testw3.xlsx");   

 XSSFWorkbook wkb = new XSSFWorkbook(); 

 XSSFSheet sheet1 = wkb.createSheet("DataStorage");
  String a3=null;

 for (int i=500,Row=0;i<=iRowsCount;i++)  {



     try
     {
         WebElement val= a2.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_result']/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[2]"));
        // WebElement val= a2.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_result']/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]"));
         String  a = val.getText(); 



         if( a.length() != 0 )

         { 

             a3=a;  

         //int length = val.length();

        System.out.print(a3 + '\n'); 

         XSSFRow excelRow = sheet1.createRow(Row++);
         XSSFCell excelCell = excelRow.createCell(0);                  
         excelCell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);                 
         excelCell.setCellValue(a3);



         for ( int j=5;j<12;j++)

         { switch (j)
             {
         case 5:val= a2.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_result']/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[5]"));excelCell = excelRow.createCell(1);                               
         excelCell.setCellValue(val.getText()); break;
         case 8:val= a2.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_result']/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[8]"));excelCell = excelRow.createCell(2);                               
         excelCell.setCellValue(val.getText());break;
         case 9:val= a2.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_result']/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[9]"));excelCell = excelRow.createCell(3);                               
         excelCell.setCellValue(val.getText());break;
         case 11:val= a2.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_result']/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[11]"));excelCell = excelRow.createCell(4);                               
         excelCell.setCellValue(val.getText());break;
             }


         }


        Thread.sleep(5000); 
         }


         else


         {

             System.out.print(a3 + '\n'); 

             XSSFRow excelRow = sheet1.createRow(Row++);
             XSSFCell excelCell = excelRow.createCell(0);                  
             excelCell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);                 
             excelCell.setCellValue(a3);



             for ( int j=5;j<12;j++)

             { switch (j)
                 {
             case 5:val= a2.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_result']/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[5]"));excelCell = excelRow.createCell(1);                               
             excelCell.setCellValue(val.getText()); break;
             case 8:val= a2.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_result']/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[8]"));excelCell = excelRow.createCell(2);                               
             excelCell.setCellValue(val.getText());break;
             case 9:val= a2.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_result']/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[9]"));excelCell = excelRow.createCell(3);                               
             excelCell.setCellValue(val.getText());break;
             case 11:val= a2.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter_result']/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[11]"));excelCell = excelRow.createCell(4);                               
             excelCell.setCellValue(val.getText());break;
                 }


             }


            Thread.sleep(5000); 
             }


     }//tryc

     catch (NoSuchElementException e) {


        }//cath

         }//for


    // System.out.println(); 
    // Thread.sleep(6000);


     fos.flush();     
     wkb.write(fos);     
     fos.close();
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Your help is much appreciated.
Best Regards.

Comment: What is the value of `iRowsCount` when you reach the `for`?

Comment: "program stopped without any error" so first of all you have to do something with catched exceptions, for example print it.

Comment: yeah, i have changed for loop (int i=500,Row=0;i<=2000;i++) , now its working fine.. seems some issue in counting row data.  thanks all..

Answer (score 0):

I have also exported web table data to an excel sheet like this,
This works fine for me. Hope this will help you.

```html
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='entireBody']/div[3]/div/table"));
    List<WebElement> tbdy = element.findElements(By.tagName("tbody"));
    List<WebElement> thed = element.findElements(By.tagName("thead"));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    List<WebElement> tr = tbdy.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    List<WebElement> trh = thed.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    try {
     String filename = Path;
     HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
     HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FirstSheet");
     CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();//Create style
        Font font = workbook.createFont();//Create font
        font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);//Make font bold
        style.setFont(font);//set it to bold
        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
        for(int i = 0; i < trh.size(); i++){
         List<WebElement> tdh =trh.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
         System.out.println("loop1");
         for (int j = 0; j < tdh.size(); j++) {
          
          row.createCell(j).setCellValue(tdh.get(j).getText());
          row.getCell(j).setCellStyle(style);
          
      }
         
         
        }
     for (int i = 0; i < tr.size(); i++) {
      HSSFRow row2 = sheet.createRow(i+1);
      List<WebElement> td = tr.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
      for (int j = 0; j < td.size(); j++) {
       td.get(j).getText();

       
       
       row2.createCell(j).setCellValue(td.get(j).getText());
      }

     }
     FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
     workbook.write(fileOut);
     fileOut.close();
     System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");
```